# Manipulate the result of PHPversion()

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to change the result of the function phpversion() ? 
Where is this value stored?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Change your php version :)

Comment: I frequently install a programm which (requires) PHP version 5.4, but I have Ubuntu 14.04 where it is not possible to install PHP 5.4

Comment: So what? changing the output won't change the version. Even if you make the programm "think" it's another version, what about all the features that that version has (that can stop your program from working)?

Comment: But how will hacking the PHPVersion result fix that? If the program requires PHP 5.4, then hacking the output from PHPVersion won't automagically mean that you're actually running PHP 5.4

Comment: And in answer to your question: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_version.h

Comment: The program works with version 5.5 but at the moment I have to comment out every version check at every installation.

Comment: Does this program really use a proper version check that limits it to PHP 5.4, or does it check for PHP >= 5.4?

Comment: The check only allows 5.3 and 5.4

Comment: Not well considered code then: but surely better to modify the check rather than to hack PHP itself to fake a version